# how to add compiler flags as in cmake `-DCMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG=xxx`

Tags: meson-build

In meson.build we can add something like `add_global_arguments(...)` or `-Dcpp_args`, but how can I make this specify to certain buildtype? I cannot find anything in the [reference table](https://mesonbuild.com/Reference-tables.html#language-arguments-parameter-names).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do that by checking for the buildtype and adding the flags inside your if-check.

```
buildtype = get_option('buildtype')
if buildtype == 'debug'
  add_project_arguments([ '-DDEBUG' ], language: 'cpp')
endif
```

You can find the possible values for the option on Meson's page on ["Built-in options"](https://mesonbuild.com/Builtin-options.html)